# php JSON data structure for angular app

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to format the a mysql response into a array of objects so that Angular can easily traverse the data.

mysql result:

```
[{
    "FIAccountsID": "99",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "1"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "99",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "2"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "100",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "1"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "100",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "2"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "101",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "1"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "101",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "2"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "102",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "1"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "102",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "2"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "103",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "1"
},
{
    "FIAccountsID": "103",
    "AccountName": "",
    "AccountCustomName": "Brothers",
    "AccountNumber": "99-123123123",
    "AccountTypeName": "IRA",
    "FinancialInstName": "Testes",
    "FinancialInstID": "9",
    "UserID": "1",
    "ofxStatusCode": "500",
    "UserAccountID": "09128-vc-12",
    "FirstName": "Someones",
    "LastName": "Name",
    "Status": "2"
}......
```

here it the PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   
{ 

  $uid = $row['UserID'];
  $name = $row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'];
  $fiid = $row['FinancialInstID'];
  $fi = $row['FinancialInstName'];
  $acctID = $row['FIAccountsID'];


  $rows[$uid]['name'] = $name;
  $rows[$uid]['uid'] = $uid;
  $rows[$uid]['fi'][$fiid]['name'] = $fi;
  $rows[$uid]['fi'][$fiid]['acct'][$acctID]['name'] = $row['AccountCustomName'];

}

print json_encode($rows);
```

this is what i get:

```
{
"1": {
    "name": "Some Name",
    "uid": "1",
    "fi": {
        "9": {
            "name": "Testes",
            "accts": {
                "99": {
                    "name": "name 1"
                },
                "100": {
                    "name": "name 2"
                },
                "103": {
                    "name": "name 3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"2": {
    "name": "Another Name",
    "uid": "2",
    "fi": {
        "7": {
            "name": "Trevor's Brokerage House",
            "accts": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "Sally's 401k Account"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "retirement"
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "Some other account"
..........
```

desired result:

```
[
  {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Some Name",
            "uid": "1",
            "fi": [
                {
                    "name": "Testes",
                    "acct": [
                        {
                            "name": "name 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "name 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "name 3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Another Name",
            "uid": "2",
            "fi": [
                {
                    "name": "Trevor's Brokerage House",
                    "acct": [
                        {
                            "name": "Sally's 401k Account"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "retirement"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Some other account"
..........
```

I want to know how to have the data structure without the unique keys prefixing the nested arrays

Comment: `$json = array('users'=>array(array('name'=>'name one', ...), array('name'=> 'name two'), ...));`

Comment: the problem is that each row in the result set writes over the last if I do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that if you define keys, `json_encode` will read them. If you don't want keys, declare the array without them. So, what you need to do is to structure your array according to you desired output.

But the way your data is arranged make it somewhat hard to format it properly. The solution I can see is to do what you're already doing:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   
{ 

  $uid = $row['UserID'];
  $name = $row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'];
  $fiid = $row['FinancialInstID'];
  $fi = $row['FinancialInstName'];
  $acctID = $row['FIAccountsID'];


  $rows[$uid]['name'] = $name;
  $rows[$uid]['uid'] = $uid;
  $rows[$uid]['fi'][$fiid]['name'] = $fi;
  $rows[$uid]['fi'][$fiid]['acct'][$acctID]['name'] = $row['AccountCustomName'];

}
```

But then you revisit the array and remove all the keys using `array_values`:

```
foreach ($rows as $uid => $data)
{
    foreach ($data['fi'] as $fiid => $fi)
    {
        $rows[$uid]['fi'][$fiid]['acct'] = array_values($fi['acct']);
    }
    $rows[$uid]['fi'] = array_values($rows[$uid]['fi']);
}
// Here you format the outer array:
$rows = array(array('users' => array_values($rows)));
```

Which gives a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "Someones Name",
                "uid": "1",
                "fi": [
                    {
                        "name": "Testes",
                        "acct": [
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Someones Name",
                "uid": "2",
                "fi": [
                    {
                        "name": "Testes",
                        "acct": [
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Brothers"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: doesn't allow for multiple users?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple users"? This way it'll have a "users" key which value is an array of users, like the example you gave.

Comment: i already have a complete working output with unique keys (it is in the original post). I want to know how to have the data structure without the unique keys prefixing the nested arays

Comment: @user2762149 I edited the answer, see if it is what you want (also, a sample of your desired output would be good, I don't know why you removed from the question).

Comment: i felt like it was confusing the question. the format i have in the question is what I want EXCEPT i don't what the indexes prefixing the nested arrays. the code you posted is the same as before?

Comment: @user2762149 I change it a little bit now (I forgot to paste the edit in the code before).

Comment: that is producing a new user, uid for each row in stead of adding the nested data to the user. the output in the question is the desired format EXCEPT i don't want the unique keys prefixing the nested arrays.

Comment: @user2762149 you'll have to be more clearer then, because I don't understand what you want. Update your question and tell, please: 1) How the original array looks like, 2) How your current output looks like and 3) How you want it to looks like.

Comment: @user2762149 I believe now I got what you want.

Comment: that is what i was wondering in the original question. if this was the only way to strip out the keys. I figured this was the case. thank you for the clarification.